# como deixar meu botão no menu marcado?

Tags: javascript, css

Quando eu clicar em um botão quero que ele fique marcado de branco, se eu clicar em outro desmarque o antigo e deixe marcada o novo

```js
var menu = document.querySelectorAll("#menu > ul > li > a");

for(var i = 0; i < menu.length; i++){
 menu[i].addEventListener("click", configMenu);
}

function configMenu(){
 for(var i = 0; i < menu.length; i++){
  menu[i].style.background = "#469c17";
 }
 this.style.background = "white";
}
```

```css
#menu{
 width: 100%;
 height: 36px;
 background-color: #469c17;
}
#posts_menu{
 margin-left: 39px;
}
#posts_menu, #chat_menu, #agenda_menu, #arquivo_menu{
 line-height: 36px;
 float: left;
 list-style: none;
}
#posts_menu a, #chat_menu a, #agenda_menu a, #arquivo_menu a{
 display: block;
 width: 100px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #469c17;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
}
#posts_menu a:hover, #chat_menu a:hover, #agenda_menu a:hover, #arquivo_menu a:hover{
 background-color: white;

}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
   <ul>
    <li id="posts_menu"><a href="post">Todos Posts</a></li>
    <li id="chat_menu"><a href="chat">Chat</a></li>
    <li id="agenda_menu"><a href="#">Agenda</a></li>
    <li id="arquivo_menu"><a href="arquivos">Arquivos</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Para que o seu exemplo fique a funcionar no *live snippet* apenas precisa de cancelar a ação de navegação de página com [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

```js
var menu = document.querySelectorAll("#menu > ul > li > a");

for(var i = 0; i < menu.length; i++){
 menu[i].addEventListener("click", configMenu);
}

function configMenu(event /*<--evento é recebido aqui*/ ){
    for(var i = 0; i < menu.length; i++){
 menu[i].style.background = "#469c17";
    }
    this.style.background = "white";
    event.preventDefault(); //<---cancelar a navegação de página
}
```

```css
#menu{
 width: 100%;
 height: 36px;
 background-color: #469c17;
}
#posts_menu{
 margin-left: 39px;
}
#posts_menu, #chat_menu, #agenda_menu, #arquivo_menu{
 line-height: 36px;
 float: left;
 list-style: none;
}
#posts_menu a, #chat_menu a, #agenda_menu a, #arquivo_menu a{
 display: block;
 width: 100px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #469c17;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
}
#posts_menu a:hover, #chat_menu a:hover, #agenda_menu a:hover, #arquivo_menu a:hover{
 background-color: white;

}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
   <ul>
    <li id="posts_menu"><a href="post">Todos Posts</a></li>
    <li id="chat_menu"><a href="chat">Chat</a></li>
    <li id="agenda_menu"><a href="#">Agenda</a></li>
    <li id="arquivo_menu"><a href="arquivos">Arquivos</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

A instrução que lhe atribui a cor branca ao elemento selecionado é:

```
this.style.background = "white";
```

E funciona porque dentro de um `eventListener` o `this` refere o elemento clicado, [como a própria documentação especifica](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_value_of_this_within_the_handler):

> If attaching a handler function to an element using
>   addEventListener(), the value of this inside the handler is a
>   reference to the element.

---

Se em contrapartida tiver várias páginas diferentes para chat, post, agenda e arquivos então precisa de interpretar em que página está e apenas mudar a cor nessa página.

Poderia obter o nome da página em que está diretamente pelo *url*:

```
let paginaAtual = window.location.pathname.split("/").pop();
```

Depois colocaria todos com a cor normal e o da pagina corrente a branco:

```
const menu = document.querySelectorAll("#menu > ul > li > a");
for(let i = 0; i < menu.length; i++){
    menu[i].style.background = "#469c17";
}

const linkAtual = document.querySelector("#menu > ul > li > a[href=" + paginaAtual +"]");
linkAtual.style.background = "white";
```

Answer (score 1):

Eis o que você busca em um exemplo funcional:

```js
var menu = document.querySelectorAll("#menu > ul > li > a");

for(var i = 0; i < menu.length; i++){
 menu[i].addEventListener("click", configMenu);
}

function configMenu(){
 for(var i = 0; i < menu.length; i++){
  menu[i].style.background = "#469c17";
 }
 this.style.background = "white";
}


function cor(){

var a = document.getElementsByTagName("A");

for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
  a[i].style.backgroundColor = "#469c17";
}



}
```

```css
#menu{
 width: 100%;
 height: 36px;
 background-color: #469c17;
}
#posts_menu{
 margin-left: 39px;
}
#posts_menu, #chat_menu, #agenda_menu, #arquivo_menu{
 line-height: 36px;
 float: left;
 list-style: none;
}
#posts_menu a, #chat_menu a, #agenda_menu a, #arquivo_menu a{
 display: block;
 width: 100px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #469c17;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
}
#posts_menu a:hover, #chat_menu a:hover, #agenda_menu a:hover, #arquivo_menu a:hover{
 background-color: white;

}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
   <ul>
    <li id="posts_menu"><a onclick='cor()' href="#">Todos Posts</a></li>
    <li id="chat_menu"><a href="#" onclick='cor()'>Chat</a></li>
    <li id="agenda_menu"><a href="#"  onclick='cor()'>Agenda</a></li>
    <li id="arquivo_menu"><a href="#"  onclick='cor()'>Arquivos</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

coloquei os `hrefs` com valor `#` somente para na hora que você clicar não mudar de pagina.

o que eu fiz foi colocar um `onclick` nos `links` que chamam a função `cor`.

e na função:

```
function cor(){

    var a = document.getElementsByTagName("A");

    for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
            a[i].style.backgroundColor = "#469c17";
    }

}
```

e resolve teu problema

Comment: Tem dois ID's nas tags. Tente dar uma breve explicação do que foi alterado e como você resolveu o problema

Comment: @Phelipe estou fazendo isso :D, mas que dois idS?

Comment: Tinha dois ID's, mas já retirou.

Comment: Julio mas se eu coloco o link (meu site esta em mvc) ele atualiza a pagina e nao aparece!! so funciona com #

Comment: @AKU esta utilizando alguma linguagem back-end? pois nesse caso seria interessante colocar ou nao a classe ativa se estiver na pagina correspondente ao link